# Constructing a nested std::array with std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++17, initializer-list, stdarray

I'm working on a templated polygon class and I'm having trouble with compiling the class...

Here is how I'm trying to instantiate it:

```
int main() {
    try {
        pipes::polygon<float, 2, 3> p1("triangle", { {0.0f,1.0f}, {1.0f,1.0f}, {2.0f,3.0f} });

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And Here is my class:

```
template<typename T, size_t DimensionSize, size_t VertexCount>
class polygon{
public:
    typedef std::array<T, DimensionSize> Dimension;
    typedef std::array<Dimension, VertexCount> Vertices;
private:
    Vertices vertices_;
    std::string name_;

public:
    polygon() = default;
    ~polygon() = default;

    polygon(const polygon& other) = default;
    polygon(polygon&& other) = default;
    
    polygon& operator=(const polygon& other) {
        vertices_ = other.vertices;
        name_ = other.name;
        return *this;
    }

    polygon(std::string_view name, std::initializer_list<Vertices> vertices) :
        name_{name}, vertices_{vertices}
    {}

    std::string name() const { return name_; }
    Vertices vertices() const { return vertices_; }
};
```

This is the compilation error from MSVC:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Simulator, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>main2.cpp
1>c:\***\vec2.h(38): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::initializer_list<std::array<std::array<T,2>,3>>' to '_Ty'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty=float
1>        ]
1>c:\***\vec2.h(38): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\***\vec2.h(36): note: while compiling class template member function 'pipes::polygon<float,2,3>::polygon(std::string_view,std::initializer_list<std::array<std::array<T,2>,3>>)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>c:\***\main2.cpp(12): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'pipes::polygon<float,2,3>::polygon(std::string_view,std::initializer_list<std::array<std::array<T,2>,3>>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>c:\***\main2.cpp(12): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'pipes::polygon<float,2,3>' being compiled
1>Done building project "Simulator.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am I declaring my constructor that is using the initializer list wrong? Or could it be from using the typedefs within my class?

Internally my `vertices_` member should be structured as such:
Dimension Size would be the number of coordinate values for each point, and the Vertex Count is how many there are to make up that polygon. As can be seen from the code above, I declared the type as `float`, a dimension of 2 with 3 vertices... therefore I'm expecting for my data structure to look like this:

```
vertices_ = { {0.0f,1.0f}, {1.0f,1.0f}, {2.0f,3.0f} };
```

Yet, I'm having trouble with getting `std::initializer_list` to do this for me.

Comment: `Vertices` is already a 2D array, so `std::initializer_list<Vertices>` expect a 3D array of float, which is probably not what you want. Replace `std::initializer_list<Vertices>` by simply `Vertices` and it should solve the issue.

Comment: @Holt oh okay, yeah something very easy to overlook... I could try that, or maybe the `initializer_list` should have `Dimension` instead of `Vertices`...

Comment: @Holt I tried replacing that and still failed...

Comment: `std::array` does not have a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`, so it would not work. If you use `Vertices` it will work but you probably need an extra pair of brackets `{}` around the array. https://godbolt.org/z/5xhd47

Comment: @Holt, okay so just use the typedef directly as the type, and the initialier_list should automatically deduce it...

Comment: @Holt okay, I'm used to using vector more often than array... But since the number of values shouldn't be that large for a general polygon... I was thinking that array would be "cache" friendly! I know there are a lot of similarities between array and vector except that vector will allocate dynamically... but never dawned on me that array doesn't support initializer_list directly.

Comment: @Holt That did the trick, thank you for the help... the only downside is that the code looks kind of cumbersome with the extra braces... having { {..}, {..}, {..} } is one thing, but having to have { { {..}, {..}, {..} } } is something else, kind of seems redundant...

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://godbolt.org/z/5h4q5e If so, I can write up an answer

Comment: @ildjarn Your code works but is much less safe than the original one.  You'd get a runtime assert error if your initializer list is the wrong size instead of a compile time one.

Comment: @Holt : This was intentional. The original code A) doesn't compile, and B) uses `initializer_list`, so the assumption was that they want a working solution using `initializer_list`. Using `array`, a C-array, or a variadic template would all be options for providing better guarantees, but that does not appear to me to be what they were attempting to do.